# Installing an item in the registry using Nant

Tags: nant, 32bit-64bit

I need to install a registry item using Nant.  However, no matter what I try, Nant *only* seems to install a 32-bit version of the item (i.e. in the Wow6432Node registry subfolder).

Here's my most recent attempt:

```
<target name="InstallMyKey">
    <property name="MyKey.reg" value="${BuildPath}\some\folder\MyKey.reg" />
    <exec program="regedit">
        <arg value="/s" />
        <arg value="${MyKey.reg}" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

I've tried using alternative commands, such as regedt32 and reg, and have tried setting the working folder to %WINDIR%\SysWOW64 and running regedit from there.  None of these worked either.

I've tried taking the very latest build of Nant (as of yesterday) and got the same issue.

Perhaps the problem is that Nant is a 32 bit exe and hence because of "file system redirection" launches the 32 bit version of regedit?

Anyone solved this?

Comment: Could this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx    It explains how a 32 bit application can specify the KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag to access a 64 bit key.   However... I don't know how to use this information to solve my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try testing it from the command prompt before testing it from NAnt, since that is what `exec` will be doing.  This would rule out any NAnt issues and confirm your syntax first.  You are right that folder redirection may be occurring, so try the explicit path of %WINDIR%\regedit.exe (SysWOW64 contains the 32-bit versions).

Comment: I've no longer got access to the environment in which I had this problem.  But as this is the only answer anyone's offered, I'll accept it :-)